# PMD Xpath to check presence Relational Expression

Tags: xpath, pmd

Wrote below Xpath , which to i want extend to include "<", ">=" etc.

```
//RelationalExpression[@Image=">" and 
descendant :: PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image!="ABC" and @Image!="PQR"]]
```

Below rule does not give correct result,

```
//RelationalExpression[@Image=">" or @Image="<" and 
descendant :: PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image!="ABC" and @Image!="PQR"]]
```

Any solution to correct the check?

Comment: Hi, please include a sample for the code you'd like to match. How is the result incorrect? What would be the correct behavior?

Comment: class test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 short sPos  = 0x8000;
 byte bFirst = 1;
    byte bSecond = 2;
 
 if(sPos > (short) 0)
 {
  System.out.println("True");
 }

 if(bFirst < bSecond)
 {
  System.out.println("True");
 }


 if(ABC(1,2) > 0)
 {
  System.out.println("True");
 }


 if(PQR(1,2) < 0)
 {
  System.out.println("True");
 }
}

  public static int ABC(int x, int y)
     {
  //compare the parameters
  return y;
     }
     public static int PQR(int x, int y)
     {
  //compare the parameters
  return y;
     }     
}

Comment: I found a way out using property name="violationSuppressXPath" of PMD, It ignores the nodes ABC ,PQR with string match. The rule is now simplidied as //RelationalExpression[@Image=">" or @Image="<"]

Comment: Is it possible that you simply forgot parentheses around the `or`? Like in many programming languages, in XPath the `and` binds more closely